# Vue.js: How to change the colors of Vue2-slider component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I am using vue-slider.
I want to change the color of the slider.
The class name is "vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner".

The picture below is the original css of vue-slider.
[image: original css code]

Now I want to change border-color and background-color like this.

```
.vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner {
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    min-width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #FBF6F7;
    background-color: #FBF6F7;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

So I tried to fix the css code in the vue code.

My template.

```
<div class="slider">
        <vue-slider
        v-model="value"
        :dragOnClick="true"
        :adsorb="true"
        :marks="data.name"
        :included="true"
        :data="bar"
        :data-value="'id'"
        :data-label="'name'"
        class="vue-slider-rail"
    ></vue-slider>
</div>
```

css

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner {
        font-size: 14px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        min-width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #FBF6F7!important;
        background-color: #FBF6F7!important;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
</style>
```

But my css code did not work, so I tried another css code.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .slider >>> .vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner {
        font-size: 14px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        min-width: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #FBF6F7!important;
        background-color: #FBF6F7!important;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
</style>
```

This code also did not work, so I need someone to help me out to change the colors.

Comment: Do you see the style in the dev-tool as override by other rules, or do you not see the rules above at all?

Comment: I don't see a rule above.

Comment: Before I submit my answer, let's make sure it's not a scope issue. If you remove the `scoped` from the style definition, do you see the rule? (you can remove the `>>>` deep selector when removing `scoped`)

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `<style>` tag is marked is `scoped`, which will keep your style only for this component template.

The style you are trying to change is actually a different component, having a different identifier.

When overwriting library components, you'll have to do it in a non-scoped style.

Personally, I'd recommend creating an `overrides.sass` file with all the different styles you wish to override in your app, and call it from a top-level component with no `scoped` attribute.

Example:
in `App.vue`:

```
<style lang="sass">
  @use './style/overrides.sass'
</style>
```

and in `/style/overrides.sass`:

```
.vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner
  font-size: 14px
  white-space: nowrap
  padding: 2px 5px
  min-width: 20px
  text-align: center
  color: #fff
  border-radius: 5px
  border-color: #FBF6F7!important
  background-color: #FBF6F7!important
  box-sizing: content-box
```

For the sake of specificity, you might want to add `!important` to all rules, or make the selection stronger:

```
.vue-slider-dot-tooltip .vue-slider-dot-tooltip-inner
  font-size: 14px
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Actually I have <style lang="scss"> section in the App.vue, so I wrote the css code there. Then I could fix the issue.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu it will work, but for sake of readability, it's recommended to move all overrides to a separate file so it's more organized. Good luck! :)